# Telebot Telegram Message with Buttons

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying create a news telegram bot. But iI can't send messages with interactive buttons.

The reason why I use the buttons is to make a menu, I would appreciate if you could show an example of making an interactive menu instead of just adding it.

Using Language : Python 3.9 & Telebot Library

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Telebot](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) provides the following types for InlineKeyboard:

- [`InlineKeyboardMarkup`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup); The keyboard
- [`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton); The markup button

---

An basic example would look like

```py
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot import types

bot = TeleBot("859163076:A......")
chat_id = 12345

button_foo = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Foo', callback_data='foo')
button_bar = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Bar', callback_data='bar')

keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.add(button_foo)
keyboard.add(button_bar)

bot.send_message(chat_id, text='Keyboard example', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

---

Which will result in the following message send to `chat_id`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this example, we create a menu with two buttons, "Button 1" and "Button 2", and process each button separately. When the user selects one of the buttons, the bot sends the corresponding message.

```py
    import telebot
    from telebot import types
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')
    
    #Command /start
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Bottom 1")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Bottom 2")
        markup.add(item1, item2)
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Select option:", reply_markup=markup)
    
    #Bottom 1
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Bottom 1")
    def button1(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "U select bottom 1")
    
    #Bottom 2
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Bottom 2")
    def button2(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "U select bottom 2")
    
    #Start bot
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

use callback query handler, there is example here:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).